# Opencart Version 2.1.0.1 SSL not working

Tags: ssl, opencart

I  know this question already asked. But those questions and answer are not working for me.

This is my question `SSL` not working in `Opencart Version 2.1.0.1`. Am using **hostgator** `cPanel`.

I did some things those are followings:

`config.php`

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

`admin/config.php`

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

`Admin->Settings->Server Tab->SSl->`**Yes**

All i did but i got error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.example.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED